# Assertion failed: Property 'FilterRestrictions' is defined twice

Tags: annotations, odata, metadata, cds

Recently, we had system upgrade from 1709 to 1809. We built Custom Fiori APP using custom CDS view and it was working fine in 1709. But after system upgrade, we got error:

assert-dbg.js:34 Assertion failed: Property 'FilterRestrictions' is defined twice; Source = metadata document, Annotation Target = z********_CDS.ZFDC_MY_DEFAULTS_CDS_Entities/Z_PROJECT_CREW, Term = Capabilities.NavigationRestrictions

The Metadata for this is as following:

```
-<Annotation Term="Capabilities.NavigationRestrictions">
-<Record>
-<PropertyValue Property="RestrictedProperties">
-<Collection>
-<Record>
<PropertyValue Property="NavigationProperty" NavigationPropertyPath="Parameters"/>
-<PropertyValue Property="FilterRestrictions">
-<Record>
<PropertyValue Bool="false" Property="Filterable"/>
</Record>
</PropertyValue>
-<PropertyValue Property="FilterRestrictions">
-<Record>
<PropertyValue Bool="false" Property="Filterable"/>
</Record>
</PropertyValue>
</Record>
</Collection>
</PropertyValue>
</Record>
</Annotation>
```

CDS view as following:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'Z_PROJ_CREW'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@EndUserText.label: 'Project maping to Crew'
define view Z_PROJECT_CREW 
    with parameters 
        p_projectId: ps_pspid,
        p_userName:  xubname 
    as select from zdef_employ {
    key zdef_employ.pernr   as PersonnelNo,  
    key zdef_employ.pspid   as ProjectID, 
    key zdef_employ.uname   as UserName, 
    zdef_employ.cname   as PersonnelName,  
    zdef_employ.post1   as ProjectName, 
    zdef_employ.deleted as Deleted,  
    zdef_employ.erdat   as CreatedOn,  
    zdef_employ.ernam   as CreatedBy,  
    zdef_employ.aedat   as ChangedOn,  
    zdef_employ.aenam   as ChangedBy
} where zdef_employ.pspid = $parameters.p_projectId 
    and zdef_employ.uname =  $parameters.p_userName
    and zdef_employ.deleted = 'N'
```

As the metadata is generated automatically, not sure how to fix it. We don't want to try modify annotation at this stage yet. Anyone has this problem? or any suggest from Experts?

I do find a sap note: 2804095 - OData metadata: Missing Capability Annotations for Navigation Restrictions. Because of the supported SP, it doesn't apply to our system.

Any Answers or suggestion? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the only change was the upgrade from 1709 to 1809, you might want to report this issue to SAP in a customer message.